# C++ SFML Performance

Tags: c++, performance, sfml

I have recently started a project using SFML in C++. So far I haven't done much but I noticed an issue. Inside of the `while(window.is_open())` loop I made a tick counter that increments every itteration through the loop, then I displayed the value with a `sf::text` object. I noticed that when I was in the starting resolution (~600 x ~400), It ran about 1000 - 1500 tick per second, but whenever I maximize, or even just increase the window size at all for that matter, the tick rate drops to around 250-500 per second. Is there anything I can do to elimante this, and possible any other performance issues I may encounter?

Comment: Throttle your framerate to max it at 60 hz, no need to draw faster than what your monitor can draw :p

Comment: Otherwise, you may use a profiler when running the code to see where the performance takes a hit.

Comment: Throttling it is probably the best solution. The number of ticks per second or frames drawn is a bad measurement. You may also want to post how you're responding to the resize event. There is some logic you may need to add to have it properly respond to a resize.